# I want to recognize multiple markers with AR.js

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, aframe

The code below is a program to play a video in AR. How can I set multiple markers to play a different video for each?
Also, can you tell me if you want to play the video and display the image separately?

I would also like to have audio on/off for each marker. css styles are omitted.
The audio on/off code has also been cut for non-demand areas.

```html
<script>
            AFRAME.registerComponent('videohandler', {
            init: function () {

                var marker = this.el;

                this.vid = document.querySelector("#vid");

                marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function () {
                    // this.vid.muted = false;
                    this.vid.play();
                    document.getElementById("volume").style.display = "block";

                }.bind(this));

                marker.addEventListener('markerLost', function() {
                    //this.vid.muted = true;
                    this.vid.pause();
                    // this.vid.currentTime = 0;
                    document.getElementById("volume").style.display = "none";

                }.bind(this));
            }
        });

        function toggleMute() {

            var video=document.getElementById("vid")

            if(video.muted){
                video.muted = false;

                document.getElementById("volume").innerHTML = '<svg version="1.1" id="muted" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 480 480" style="enable-background:new 0 0 480 480;" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M278.944,17.577c-5.568-2.656-12.128-1.952-16.928,1.92L106.368,144.009H32c-17.632,0-32,14.368-32,32v128 c0,17.664,14.368,32,32,32h74.368l155.616,124.512c2.912,2.304,6.464,3.488,10.016,3.488c2.368,0,4.736-0.544,6.944-1.6 c5.536-2.656,9.056-8.256,9.056-14.4v-416C288,25.865,284.48,20.265,278.944,17.577z"/> <path d="M368.992,126.857c-6.304-6.208-16.416-6.112-22.624,0.128c-6.208,6.304-6.144,16.416,0.128,22.656 C370.688,173.513,384,205.609,384,240.009s-13.312,66.496-37.504,90.368c-6.272,6.176-6.336,16.32-0.128,22.624 c3.136,3.168,7.264,4.736,11.36,4.736c4.064,0,8.128-1.536,11.264-4.64C399.328,323.241,416,283.049,416,240.009 S399.328,156.777,368.992,126.857z"/> <path d="M414.144,81.769c-6.304-6.24-16.416-6.176-22.656,0.096c-6.208,6.272-6.144,16.416,0.096,22.624 C427.968,140.553,448,188.681,448,240.009s-20.032,99.424-56.416,135.488c-6.24,6.24-6.304,16.384-0.096,22.656 c3.168,3.136,7.264,4.704,11.36,4.704c4.064,0,8.16-1.536,11.296-4.64C456.64,356.137,480,299.945,480,240.009 S456.64,123.881,414.144,81.769z"/> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>';

            } else {
                video.muted = true;
                document.getElementById("volume").innerHTML = '<svg id="unmuted" enable-background="new 0 0 448.046 448.046" viewBox="0 0 448.046 448.046" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m358.967 1.614c-5.6-2.72-12.128-1.952-16.928 1.92l-155.648 124.512h-74.368c-17.664 0-32 14.336-32 32v128c0 17.664 14.336 32 32 32h74.368l155.616 124.512c2.912 2.304 6.464 3.488 10.016 3.488 2.336 0 4.704-.544 6.944-1.6 5.536-2.656 9.056-8.256 9.056-14.4v-416c0-6.144-3.52-11.744-9.056-14.432z"/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/></svg>';
            }

        }

        
        function alertInfo() {
            var element = document.getElementById("infoBox");
            element.classList.toggle("active");

            var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
            overlay.classList.toggle("active");

        }

        function cloasAlert() {
            var cloasAlertInfo = document.getElementById("overlay");
            cloasAlertInfo.classList.remove("active");

            var hideAlert = document.getElementById("infoBox");
            hideAlert.classList.remove("active");

        }
        </script>
    <a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
    device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false"
    embedded
    gesture-detector
    >
      <a-assets>
        <video
    id="vid"
    src="assets/asset.mp4"
    preload="auto"
    response-type="arraybuffer"
    loop
    crossorigin
    webkit-playsinline
    muted
    playsinline
    ></video>
        <audio src="videopath" autoplay></audio>
      </a-assets>
      <a-marker
    type="pattern"
    preset="custom"
    url="assets/marker.patt"
    videohandler
    smooth="true"
    smoothCount="10"
    smoothTolerance="0.01"
    smoothThreshold="5"
    raycaster="objects: .clickable"
    emitevents="true"
    cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;"
    id="markerA"
    >
        <a-video
    src="#vid"
    scale="1 1 1"
    position="0 0.1 0"
    rotation="-90 0 0"
    class="clickable"
    gesture-handler
    ></a-video>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
```

Comment: different videos for different marker patterns?